# Composer cannot build composer.lock for yii2 basic preset

Tags: php, yii2, composer-php

I've followed the installation tutorial in  this [Document](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html)

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:^1.2.0"
composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

But it given me this error.

```js
"Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.4 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.3 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.2 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.1 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.0 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.9 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.8 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.7 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.6 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.5 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - yiisoft/yii2 2.0.10 requires bower-asset/jquery 2.2.*@stable | 2.1.*@stable | 1.11.*@stable | 1.12.*@stable -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 ^2.0 -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.10, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

..And this is my golbal composer.json

```
{
    "require": {
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "*"
    }
}
```

I have tried many work-around on stackoverflow, including reinstallation of this `fxp/composer-asset-plugin` ... none of the version of this plugin worked for me....

I'm thinking reason slow networkl

Comment: instead of `*` use ` ^1.2.0` in composer.json

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI An equivalent version with your suggestion already installed, `fxp/composer-asset-plugin 1.2.2` , but still I can never get through this error